# Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi)

Tags: crystal-reports

I got this error:

An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required. Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

I changed property to x86 and I install crystal report but don't resove yet

Answer (score 0):

I installed CRRedist2008_x86 and solve my problem.